# How can I apply pseudo class by condition in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-ng-class

I have the following css

```
#auction-history div:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -8px;
    background: #bad3e0;
    left: 0;
}
```

this css will be applied always on my div.

I need to have this pseudoclass on condition in my Html based on boolean.

So when i have

```
isLoading = true or false
```

i need to bind to this is loading property and if it is true - I don't want to appky thius pseudeo class on my div if it is false I need to apply

I know that I can apply classes in Angular on condition with `ngClass` but I don't know how can i do this with pseudo classes.

Comment: Have you tried the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just "re-think" your css, e.g. you can use "not"

```
#auction-history:not(.loading) div:after {
    content: "";
    ...
}
```

Your .html

```
<div #auction-history [class.loading]="yourVariable">...</div>
```

or a simple class

```
#auction-history.not-loading div:after {
    content: "";
    ...
}
 <div #auction-history [class.not-loading]="yourVariable">...</div>
```

NOTE: You can use `[ngClass]`or `[ngStyle]` or `[style.property]="variable"` or `[class.classname]="variable"`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a additional class with `::after` to handle this.

Example:

**HTML**

```
<p [class.show--after]="isLoading  == true">My name is Adrita</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.show--after::after {
   content: ' - After content';
 }
```

**[StackBiltz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wh2xke?file=src/app/app.component.html)**